# Export data in xml file from a purchase in spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, export, spree

I need to export the data of a purchase in spree commerce to xml.
The idea is that when a purchase is completed the data (name, username, product) should automatically be exported into an xml file.
I'm new to ruby/rails and spree and have no idea how to do this - can anyone please help me with this?

Using:
ruby 1.9.3p194
Rails 3.2.7
Spree 1.1.3

Thanks
Reto

The data exchange will be done with SOAP interface - I just have to generate the xml file the rest will be done by the other part 
Thanks 
Reto

Comment: what are you planning to do with your xml?

Comment: The data exchange will be done with SOAP interface - I just have to generate the xml file the rest will be done by the other part

Comment: why would you want to do that?  a rails app is already a restful webservice.  you can just add an xml view to the required action and you are done

Comment: i've no idea of xml - so how to do this:  add an xml view to the required action and you are done

Answer (score 1):

RoR allows you to render the data in the format of your choice : html, xml, json,etc. 
You can add the following in your respond_to block in the required action in your controller:

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @purchase.to_xml, :only => [:name, :username, :product] }
```

Considering your purchase object has the desired fields and you only need to display those fields, you can do something like the above example.
The :only option takes an array of model attributes and your xml will display only those attributes. 
 Refer [this doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001145) for more options.

This xml will be available via a url: www.your-website.com/your-action.xml.